# How to find distances between countries based on borders in R?

Tags: r, distance

I'm trying to get the distances from one country to a list of other countries based on the countries border in R.

I was able to find one example: [Closest distance between countries](https://egallic.fr/en/closest-distance-between-countries/) but it is using the package "maps" which doesn't seem to work anymore.

```
library(maps)
library(geosphere)
library(dplyr)

world.map <- map(database = "world", fill = TRUE)
```

Resulting error:

> Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : argument ".f" is missing, with no default

Also, I was able to find the package [cepiigeodist](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cepiigeodist/cepiigeodist.pdf) but that package calculates distances based on city not borders.

Do you know of another package I could use or how I could fix the code to work?

Comment: I tried out these packages in my system and they work without any issues. On the other hand, the article has some lines with errors but the job was done by the author. From this link, http://egallic.fr/R/Blog/Cartes/countries_distances.csv you can download a CSV with 34,410 distances in km calculated by him.

Comment: `purrr` package (related to `dplyr`) has a function called `map(.x, .f)`. It could be a name issue. Try `maps::map(database = "world", fill = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

You can get country data boundaries from `rnaturalearth` package - other data sources are available and might be more timely or correct or detailed. I've not even checked this has Sudan/South Sudan yet. Anyway:

```
> library(rnaturalearth)
> af =  ne_countries(continent = 'africa', returnclass="sf")
```

At that point, `plot(af$geom)` shows a map of Africa - and yes, South Sudan is in there so the data is at least that recent.

Now lets get the distance from each African country to the (pick one...) third in the data, which is:

```
> af$admin[3]
[1] "Benin"
```

By using `st_distance`:

```
> d = st_distance(af[3,],af)
```

Which will give the nearest distance between the countries and will (I think) use lat-long spherical geometry.

`d` is a matrix with one row (because we are measuring from one country (Benin) to all the others. You can compute the full distance matrix with `st_distance(af, af)`:

```
> d
Units: [m]
        [,1]    [,2] [,3] [,4]    [,5]    [,6]   [,7]     [,8]    [,9]   [,10]
[1,] 1608801 3095070    0    0 3369528 1266540 405106 664284.2 1663688 1234170
       [,11]    [,12]   [,13]   [,14]   [,15]    [,16]    [,17]    [,18]
[1,] 4133749 755594.6 2546200 3557286 3219007 952563.6 54052.73 964471.8
```

The zeroes should be the neighbours of Benin:

```
> af$admin[as.numeric(d)==0]
[1] "Benin"        "Burkina Faso" "Niger"        "Nigeria"      "Togo"
```

Including Benin itself.